# Switch between a normal "light" color scheme and dark night mode theme in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, stylesheet

I've been asked to implement a Day/Night mode in the page I'm maintaining.
The idea is that the default theme is a light coloured theme with light background and darker fonts and pressing a button swithing to night mode and back.

In a hand made site this looks easier by only switching between 2 .css files or overwritting colours with another one when required, at least that's how I think I would do it.

But in wordpress I don't know what would be the best way to achieve this.
I looked for a plugin that does this and inverts my styles colours in some way to create a dark mode but could not find anything like this.
As I see I will have to do it myself manually, what would be the better logical way of achieving this?

Just asking about the procedure and what files should I modify or touch.
Should I create another style.css and change it? Would it affect only the user that is performing the change on his/her browser and not globally?

Answer (score 3):

Append a `night-mode` class to your body element when "night-mode" is engaged (script.js).

```
$('#night-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').addClass('night-mode');
});
```

Then add some CSS (style.css):

```
body.night-mode #somediv {
    //night mode styles go here
}

body.night-mode #someotherdiv {
    //night mode styles go here
}

body.night-mode #someotherdiv a {
    //night mode styles go here
}
// etc etc etc for each style you need to change
```

Now, this is a very poor implementation (and not very descriptive) because you haven't really provided any examples of the code you're working with, so I have to assume you have very limited access to altering code for your site/theme.

Comment: No, I have full access to the code and I in fact had to make a child-theme for changing very specific things in my site.
I just don't know what code to provide.
I understand what you say. Would there be any problem with a plugin that codes some of it's own css rules as !important?
In fact it marks as !important some "color" rules that I would need to change in the night mode. So maybe I would be forced to change the plugin i'm using for another one that does the same but not limiting that much on styles.

Comment: Hard to say, there's a lot of different factors at play. Try adding your own `!important` to your styles and see what happens. Then post another question regarding that if it doesn't work for you.